# php and html tag problem when customizing menu items

Tags: routes

I was trying to print the menu item description under the menu name.

I add this into the menu.inc under bootstrap theme, where the function bootstrap_menu_link(array $variables) is:

```
if ($element['#original_link']['menu_name'] == "main-menu" && isset($element['#localized_options']['attributes']['title'])){
    $element['#title'] .="<br> " . $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['title'];
  }
```

my interface then showed something like `product<br>LED Drivers` as the menu item - the `<br>` tag is printed out directly. I looked at the source code, that area shows: `&lt;br&gt;` , so I then tried using `&lt;br&gt;` in the php string, but the source code showed `&amp;lt;br&amp;gt;` this time. How can I correctly insert html tag into $element['#title']?

Comment: Can you paste the whole function or at least the part that `return`s the value or constructs the `<a>` html? It should be possible just to pass in `array('html' => TRUE)` to the options of the `url()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if where the call to the l() function is created (in the function mentioned: **bootstrap_menu_link**), the third parameter contains the following element in the array:

```
'html' => TRUE
```

This tells drupal to output the title of the link as html and not run it trough check_plain().

Also, I would create a custom theme based on the bootstrap theme and add my customization there.